# How to represent a logical model in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I will do my best to explain my current problem:

Imagine I have something like this:

`(a and b(c or d))`

where `a,b,c` are all of the same type.

I would like to

a) store the information in a DB (SQLSERVER)
b) recreate the above based on the stored data.

I guess my question is..How do I represent in a DB similar types that can be connected to one another through the use of ANDs and ORs pairwise, and can also be nested in parenthesis.

The best thought I had was save the info as a string, replacing `a,b,c` with their respective DB IDs, and then when information is pulled from the DB, replace the IDs with the  actual items and evaluate on the spot.

I guess I wonder if there's a better practices way. Sorry if this isn't clear, not a DB expert - did my best to explain !

UPDATE **
think of A, B, etc, to be foreign keys to function types that, when run, return any of three values : True, False, N/A. I am trying to think of a way to pair a number of such functiontypes together, through the use of ANDs, ORs, and brackets. I do not think it's easily done with tables though :(

Comment: Can you give a better example of what a, b and c could be? specifically, what does `b(c or d)` mean? (Is it perhaps supposed to be `(a and b and (c or d))`? Are they basically boolean values?

Comment: Related? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183903/storing-and-parsing-boolean-expressions-in-database .

Comment: Ok, so in the example above, `(a and b(c or d))` effectively means `(a and X)` where x is the result of calling function `b` with `"c or d"` as a parameter - is that correct?

Comment: Not quite related - think of it like this. To evaluate access in a resource, a series of policies must be evaluated. Each policy is stored separately and has its own pipeline of evaluation (done this). But someone should be able to combine different policies to do different things. I think I'll have to store as string and use business logic on code.

Comment: No, sorry for not explaining well Kjartan: a, b,c, ds are all functions. All of them return a boolean result. Then these results are evaluated based on parenthesis and ANDs and ORs between the functions. My question is, is there a way to store such functions against one another using a table? (each function type has an ID, so that is not a problem )

Comment: Technical comment: When you reply to a comment, add a notification to the commentator: e.g. when you reply to me, start your comment with @ispiro (Just type in @i and select by clicking the tab button.) That way - the commentator gets a notification that you replied. (Not needed when commenting on actual posts.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're on the right track.

I would create one table for the functions, so each of them had an ID to use, and a separate table for the logical expressions. Depending on the complexity of the expressions (?), these might be represented in a "plain" string format, a lot like in your example, or perhaps in an XML-format. The latter would allow for adding attributes, which might be useful for info about relationships between the functions, or any other metadata.

I think it makes sense to think of each of these logical expressions as a single "item". Therefore it also feels reasonable to me to store them and express each of them as a single "item" (that is, as a single DB record).

Expressing logical statements like this in XML or something similar should not be too difficult. Doing it directly in a DB is probably also possible, but my hunch is it will be a lot more complicated to define all necessary relationships in a way that is both meaningful and complete, and also not too difficult to read and understand afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, here goes nothing !