# Save on database boolean expressions

Tags: sql, database, postgis, boolean-expression

I'm working on a web app about online questionnaires forms and i'm having a problem regarding saving on database question's visibility.

In our forms the visibility of some questions is conditioned by the answers of other questions, for example you can see question "B" only if you answered question "A".

For this simple case i have no problem to insert this information in the database, the problem is when i have visibility's condition like this: D = (A AND B) OR C.

I found this post on stackoverflow with a similar problem but the final solution was not posted: [storing and parsing boolean expressions in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183903/storing-and-parsing-boolean-expressions-in-database)

I can serialize the formula and save the string on the DB but i don't like this solution cause i lose all the DB bond, i thought to save for each condition the next condition and specify the logical connective but this solution is not good for the parenthesis; the only good idea for now is to save the single condition on a table and the condition's relation on an other table; any suggestion please?

Comment: Why you try to save it that way?. Maybe another approach is easier and better like storing if a user has answered the question or not and calculate the visibility of the others each time you show them instead of storing the logical formulas.

Comment: To do this i have to implement each single visibility logic in the code instead to make something that work for all.

Comment: You can implement de visibility with a view or stored procedure that calculate it for every question in your database.

Comment: And how i can do this?

Comment: This is too much to explain it here. Just think on the idea an then try to do it yourself. Sorry